# AVAsset(url: url).isPlayable slowing collection view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` that contains an `AVPlayer`. On `cellForItemAtIndexpath` I need to check if a `URL` I'm assigning to the `AVPlayer` is playable. I use the following code:

```
guard AVAsset(url: url).isPlayable else {
   ...
}
```

But when I scroll my `UICollectionView` it freezes for a second whilst it checks whether the url is playable. How can I make this happen asynchronously?

Comment: Did you try using GCD to dispatch the `.isPlayable` part asynchronously to a background queue?

Comment: @Pranay I have indeed, didn't make a difference

Comment: So I guess that `AVAsset(url: url).isPlayable` takes some time. What about instead checking that value beforehand? When you parse your object or something in background, add a property `let urlPlayable: Bool` which is `AVAsset(url:url).isPlayable`, and so your test is the `guard myObject.urlPlayable else {...}` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading) on Apple's documentation. Try something like this:

```
func isPlayable(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let playableKey = "playable"
    asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [playableKey]) {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: playableKey, error: &error)
        let isPlayable = status == .loaded
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(isPlayable)
        }
    }
}
```